# Parsing arabic text with SBJson in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, nsstring, arabic

i have a JSON file that i'm trying to parse using SBJson.

the response string that i'm receiving is displaying arabic characters correctly when i do a

```
NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
```

but whenever i use the SBJson parser

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
```

and try

```
NSLog(@"%@", myDictionary);
```

my arabic characters are transformed to something weird:

```
\U0633\U0627\U0642\U064a\U0629 \U0627\U0644\U0645\U0633\U0643
```

please can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\U0633\U0627\U0642\U064a\U0629 \U0627\U0644\U0645\U0633\U0643" is actually just the encoding that Objective-C uses for none ascii characters. Try adding a subview/label on whatever you're testing with which will display the text. First try with "responseString" and then "myDictionary" it *could* display the same.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry. All is well.

```
\u0633
```

is equivalence to

```
س
```

try this in C++:

```
std::wstring tStr = L"\u0633";
```

tStr will equal to س

Just NSLog is not converting

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
NSStringEncoding Arabicencoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsArabic);
    NSString *yourstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:yourdata encoding:Arabicencoding];
```